# What is the HTML tag cleaned_tag?

Tags: html

I've seen this tag in emails and some forums. It must be non-standard, because I could not find any information on the meaning of this tag.

What's the purpose of `cleaned_tag`?

### Examples

```
<cleaned_tag http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<cleaned_tag name="Author" content="Martin Holman">
<cleaned_tag name="GENERATOR" content="Mozilla/4.73 (Macintosh; U; PPC) [Netscape]">
<cleaned_tag type="text/css">...</cleaned_tag>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The web mailers IMP seems to use it](http://lists.horde.org/archives/imp/Week-of-Mon-20031110/035579.html).

From the comment:

> Get all tags that might cause trouble - `<script>`, `<embed>`,
>             etc. Meta refreshes and iframes, too

Comment: +1. But I don't see any reason to not simply remove the `meta` elements.

Comment: It removes much more than `<meta>`. It also disables scripts, frames, etc to prevent XSS attacks. If the element would be removed completely, debugging problems with the code would be hard since you can't guess which changes the script made.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad practice : using a nonexistent tag to remove an element's effect.

Another (slightly less) bad practice here could have been to comment the whole set :

```
<!--
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="Author" content="Martin Holman">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Mozilla/4.73 (Macintosh; U; PPC) [Netscape]">
<meta type="text/css">...</meta>
-->
```

The reason might be a developer not having a source management system, or a proxy or any kind of transformer removing useless or unwanted elements.

The whole should have been removed instead, especially for elements in head which won't be visible to the user.

Comment: Why is commenting with `<!-- -->` a bad practice?